# Getting wrong results on joins in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have database Schema where employees are registered, those employees are assigned jobs in terms of project.

1 employee can work on many jobs, eg. employee `John` is on `project` `abc` on task `123`. Employee `John` is also on `project` `abc` but on task `789`.

The `456` task is assign to someone else, but that's another issue.

So we have John working on same project for different tasks, because of which I have two entries in my assign_job table.

Let's see the image in little schema below:

[image]

This schema is fine. The problem I am now facing is that I want to have timeSchedule tables. So I added two tables for Time Schedule.

To which new schema would be below:

[image]

I added some dummy entries to the two new tables for two projects as listed below.

1. Recruitment & Selection
2. Training & Development

For project 1, I added 31 entries i.e. for every day there is some time of worked the employee has done. But for project 2 the employee worked only 1 day.

Now I ran this query which I think is not the right way to create joins in this situation. I am posting this question as I am getting the wrong results for the data in the database.

```
SELECT 
TS.`date_created` AS TimeSheetMonth, 
TSD.`project_id` AS ProjectID, 
TSD.`date` AS WorkDate, 
TSD.`hours` AS WorkHours, 
TS.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
E.`full_name` AS EmployeeName,
MLP.`project_title` AS ProjectTitle,
TS.`id` AS TimeSheetID
FROM timesheet TS
INNER JOIN timesheet_details TSD
ON TS.`id`= TSD.`timesheet_id`
INNER JOIN employee E
ON E.`employee_id` = TS.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN assign_job AJ
ON AJ.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` AND AJ.`trashed` = 0
INNER JOIN ml_projects MLP
ON AJ.`project_id` = MLP.`project_id`
INNER JOIN ml_projects TMLP
ON TMLP.`project_id` = TSD.`project_id`
WHERE TS.`id`=1
GROUP BY TSD.`timesheetDetails_id`, TSD.`project_id`
```

As you can see in below screen shot I am getting the project name for project id 1 whereas I am getting 2 as Project ID. Maybe there are more issues. What am I doing wrong in these joins?

[image]

### Update

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc4585/1)**

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc4585/1
```

I want individual records as I want to show it inside the table look like below one.

[image]

Comment: upvoted just for the effort you made to make your question look good!

Comment: Remove `AND AJ.trashed = 0` and write it in where clause. Also instead of AND AJ.`trashed` = 0 use `AND AJ.employee_id = TS.employee_id`. Also join on AJ.project_id and TSD.project_id is missing. And your group by has TSD.`timesheetDetails_id` but not in select?

Comment: I am not sure why you need to join to ml_project twice and then use different columns from those two tables? I believe that in this case it is not needed.
Fiish that relationship diagram and that will make things easier

Comment: @Konstantin
Yes u are right thats why i am asking the question how to connect the project_id inside the timesheet_details to the ml_projects project_id?? How can i tell that employee has worked 6 hours on which project in timesheet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timesheet` table or whatever your want to name it, needs only one foreign key - `job_id` that refers to assign_job_id and hours spent on that assignment. And no keys for `employee_id` or `project_id` because the `assign_job` already has that info. I don't want to write the code for you because i can see that you can do it yourself.

You join your timesheet to assign_job and join that one to employee and project - voila. You can then group by employee or/and by project or/and task. it's all there

Comment: Thankyou. Seems to me you are right. didnt thought of that, i was getting to projects directly which was creating the issue for me.. 
Will give feed back here after doing the required changes..

Comment: Thank yourself - with the diagram you made it is easy to spot where you were not sure what to do. All the queries just muddle the picture, which is worth 100 words :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way;

```
SELECT 
    TSD.`project_id` AS ProjectID, 
    TSD.`date` AS WorkDate, 
    TSD.`hours` AS WorkHours, 
    TS.`date_created` AS TimeSheetMonth,
    TS.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
    TS.`id` AS TimeSheetID,
    E.`full_name` AS EmployeeName,
    MLP.`project_title` AS ProjectTitle
FROM
    timesheet TS
    INNER JOIN timesheet_details TSD ON TS.`id`= TSD.`timesheet_id`
    INNER JOIN employee E ON E.`employee_id` = TS.`employee_id`
    INNER JOIN assign_job AJ ON AJ.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` 
    INNER JOIN ml_projects MLP ON AJ.`project_id` = MLP.`project_id`
    -- INNER JOIN ml_projects TMLP ON TMLP.`project_id` = TSD.`project_id` -- what for?
WHERE 
    TS.`id`=1
    AND AJ.`trashed` = 0
GROUP BY 
    TSD.`timesheetDetails_id`, TSD.`project_id`
```

Comment: im getting error sir. `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'E.`full_name` AS EmployeeName,
    MLP.`project_title` AS ProjectTitle
FROM
    ' at line 8`

Comment: Benni, your code looks great, i wish every one would take time to make it look like this. Since OPs query is almost unreadable - what is the difference besides AJ.trashed in where clause? and missing comma after TS.`id` AS TimeSheetID

Comment: it was syntax problem. you forgot the comma after TimeSheetID thats why i was getting syntax error and added extra comma after the ProjectTitle Under the Select Statement. Plus its the same result that i am getting now. nothing changed.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the Input, I updated my answer. @Sizzling Code: Why do you Need to join the 2nd time over ml_projects (alias TMLP)? Can you just remove this?

Comment: Sure. I just want results. i dont care for less or more joins, if i get good results then joins are fine by me.. I want project Title.
But if you see the table i have timeSheet details where there is daily hours employee has worked on project. Then how will you know that how much time that employee has worked on which project???
Need to use that project_id inside that timesheet details i suppose??
Plus I updated my question, Added as Fiddle in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just Need something like this:

```
SELECT 
    concat(TS.`employee_id`, " - ", E.`full_name`) as employee,
    concat(TSD.`project_id`, " - ", MLP.`project_title`) as Project,
    TS.`date_created` AS TimeSheetMonth,
    sum(1) as WorkDaysOnProjectInMonth,
    sum(TSD.`hours`) AS WorkHoursOnProjectInMonth

FROM
    timesheet TS
    INNER JOIN timesheet_details TSD ON TS.`id`= TSD.`timesheet_id`
    INNER JOIN employee E ON E.`employee_id` = TS.`employee_id`
    INNER JOIN assign_job AJ ON AJ.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` 
    INNER JOIN ml_projects MLP ON AJ.`project_id` = MLP.`project_id`
WHERE 
    TS.`id`=1
    AND AJ.`trashed` = 0
GROUP BY
        1,2
```

**EDIT**

Wow, hard question! But I think this solves your Problem:

```
SELECT 
    aj.PROJECT_ID,AJ.`employee_id`,
    mlp.project_title,
    e.full_name,
    TS.id,
    TSD.date, TSD.hours

FROM
   assign_job AJ 
    INNER JOIN ml_projects MLP ON AJ.`project_id` = MLP.`project_id` -- P:1
    INNER JOIN employee E ON AJ.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id`
    INNER JOIN timesheet TS ON E.`employee_id` = TS.`employee_id`
    INNER JOIN timesheet_details TSD ON TS.`id`= TSD.`timesheet_id`

WHERE 
    TS.`id`=1
    AND AJ.`trashed` = 0
```

Comment: Thankyou for effort. but i want individual result for every hour, as i want to display record of every hour on the table.

Comment: updated the screenshot in which i have shown a table where i want to poplulate the record.